# Can I use JBoss JDBC adapter outside of application server?

Tags: java, jdbc, jboss, junit, application-server

Can I use the JDBC adapter that is used by JBoss Application Server (preferably version 4.2.3)
outside of the application server?

*Background:* I have a problem that occurs sometimes on the application server and the stacktrace starts in `org.jboss.resource.adapter.jdbc.BaseWrapperManagedConnection` and I want have it covered by JUnit tests that run standalone.
I use JBoss's transaction manager already, should it be required.

*Note:* I know the reason of the exception thrown in the app server, this is not the problem. But I want to have it reproducible in tests: one, to be sure I really fix it, two, to know there are no such problems in other places of the app.

Answer (score 0):

`BaseWrapperManagedConnection` is implementation of `javax.resource.spi.ManagedConnection` which is part of **JCA** SPI interface. If you only need to focus on JDBC issue, I don't think worth involving complex JCA things here.

Comment: This is not really JDBC issue alone. If it was I would have no problem reproducing it. The exact exception message is `You cannot set autocommit during a managed transaction!`. I didn't cite it before, because I'm not asking "what that means?" but "how to reproduce it?"